# How to compute week and month wise percentage from day wise percentage?

Tags: summation, percentages, data-analysis, calculator

I have day wise participation percentage for a group of customers, for the whole year.

My data is as follows:

- Day 1: 100%
- Day 2: 50%
- Day 3: 0%
- Day 4: 12%
- Day 5: 2%

and so on till Day 365: 0%

My question is how can I group the above data into weekly and monthly data?

For example, how I need the data in terms of weeks:

- Week 1: 100%
- Week 2: 40%

and so on till Week 52.

For example, how I need the data in terms of months:

- Month 1: 90%
- Month 2: 35%

and so on till Month 12.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the size of the group of customers constant throughout the sample period?

Comment: Yes, the data size is constant i.e. for 365 days. However, based on the selected year, percentages can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you said that the number of customers is constant, say $N$.

So every day $N$ people can participate and in a whole week $7N$ people can participate.

The percentages give you the absolute number of people participating at a given day by multiplying it with $N$.

For example on day 1 100% of customers participate, meaning there are $1\cdot N$ customers.
On day 2 50% of customers participate, thus there are $0.5\cdot N$ customers.

Now to calculate the percentage of a whole week you just add the number of participants at each day of the week and divide by the total number of people that could have participated (and then multiply by 100 to get the percentage).

So if $p_d$ is the percentage of people participating at day $d$, then the percentage $P_{\text{week}_1}$ of people participating in the first week will be:

\begin{align} P_{\text{week}_1}&=\left(\frac{\sum_{d=1}^{7} \frac{p_d}{100}\cdot N}{7N}\right)\cdot 100\quad\%\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^{7} \frac{p_d}{7} \quad\% \end{align}

For the next week you start the sum at $d=8$  and sum up to $d=14$ etc.

Getting the percentages for the months is an analogous process.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thank you!